# Unable to get correct knockout binding context

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following javascript that does my knockout binding.

```
var context = this;

var viewModel = {
    lineitems: [{
        quantity: ko.observable(1),
        title: 'bar',
        description: 'foo',
        price: ko.observable(10),
        total: ko.observable(10),
        formattedTotal: ko.computed({
        read: function () { 
            return '$' + this.price().toFixed(2);
        },
        write: function (value) { 
            value = parseFloat(value.replace(/[^\.\d]/g, ""));
            this.price(isNaN(value) ? 0 : value);
        } 
       })
    }]
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Which binds as expected, however when I apply the formattedTotal, I get the following javascript error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'price'
```

I've tried a few changes to the syntax, but I can't seem to get it right, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are You sure that is the right fiddle for this?

Comment: completely the wrong one. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is inside your `formattedTotal` method: the scope - `this` - is not your viewModel. Try this:

```
var viewModel = {
    lineitems: [{
        quantity: ko.observable(1),
        title: 'bar',
        description: 'foo',
        price: ko.observable(10),
        total: ko.observable(10),
        formattedTotal: ko.computed({
        read: function () { 
            return '$' + viewModel.lineitems.price().toFixed(2);
        },
        write: function (value) { 
            value = parseFloat(value.replace(/[^\.\d]/g, ""));
            viewModel.lineitems.price(isNaN(value) ? 0 : value);
        } 
       })
    }]
};
```

Consider using a constructor function for your viewmodels instead of an object literal; this makes dealing with scope issues easier and cleaner. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992298/observable-not-defined-inside-object-literal-knockout) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is not a best idea to use `this` in JavaScript. Especially with Knockout. You never know what `this` will be during execution.

So I recommend writing it this way:

```
function LineItem(_quantity, _title, _description, _price) {
    var self = this;

    self.quantity = ko.observable(_quantity);
    self.title = ko.observable(_title);
    self.description = ko.observable(_description);
    self.price = ko.observable(_price);

    self.total = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.price() * self.quantity();
    }, self);

    self.formattedTotal = ko.computed(function () {
        return '$' + self.total().toFixed(2);
    }, self);
};

var viewModel = {
    lineItems: [
    new LineItem(10, 'Some Item', 'Some description', 200),
    new LineItem(5, 'Something else', 'Some other desc', 100)
]
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

You can read some discussion about `self=this` pattern [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371333/is-var-self-this-a-bad-pattern)